How do I stop a working mp3? - sound.play("file.mp3");
I want to make an MP3 player that plays music with electron (javascript). Play music no problem but I can't stop it.
npm i sound-play

const sound = require("sound-play");
sound.play("file.mp3");


Despite all my searches, I could not find a stop command for Sound Play. I would be happy if you help me.
I've been researching this for about a week now but I couldn't find a solution online.

sound.pause() to pause then sound.currentTime = 0 to reset it to the beginning of the MP3.

Inspecting the index.js from src dir of the sound-play, it seems there is no pause or stop module exported
Instead use npm play-sound
